# CSS Text transform character

Tags: css, character-encoding, lowercase

I am using `text-transform: lowercase;` code to lowercase my users posts. But when i use this code characters like: "i,ş,ç,ü,ğ" are become something else. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The declaration `text-transform: lowercase` leaves lowercase letters intact. It is very unlikely that any browser has a problem with this. If you remove the CSS declaration, you will most probably see the letters already as “something else”.

The odds are that the problem is elsewhere, in the transfer of user input to web page content. It is easy to go wrong here, due to character encoding problems. More information about the situation (a URL would be good start, and so would a description of “something else”) is needed to analyze them, and the issue would fall under a different heading.

Regarding lowercasing, it should normally be performed server-side, not in CSS. Note that the `text-transform: lowercase` cannot properly handle Turkish or Azeri text, as it unconditionally maps both “I” and “İ” to “i”, not to “ı” and “i”. Proper support to them has been promised for [Firefox 14](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-transform), presumable to be used when the content language has been suitably defined using the `lang` attribute, but it will take a long time before such processing is common across browsers. In server-side processing, it is usually very easy to deal with this as a special case.

Answer (score 0):

Does not seems like `text-transform` should cause any issues

http://jsfiddle.net/m9fpX/

are you setting

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```